# Background image not getting vertically stretched in Chrome

Tags: css

The CSS -

```
#header {       
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(images/header-bg.png) top repeat-x #FFFFFF;        
    position: relative;        
    border: none;           
    display: block;
    height: 125px;   
    width:100%;
}
```

The HTML -

```
<div id="header">
    <a href="http://localhost/" title="Dev" id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

This works good in Firefox -

[image]

But not in Chrome :( -

[image]

The image isn't being stretched vertically in Chrome.

Help!

Just a note, I'm on Linux.

Edit : The background image (50x112px) -

[image]

Check it out here - http://movie-buffs.info/

Comment: Is it supposed to be stretched vertically? Where are you telling it to do that?

Comment: I don't think CSS *can* stretch `background-image`.

Comment: I think the bug is in FF not in Chrome, what's the height of your image? like 125px or like 35px?

Comment: Needless to say, this isn't reproducible: http://jsfiddle.net/kJ3sJ/1/ I've only seen something similar in IE6, when I used a PNG fixing script.

Comment: @Kobi I think CSS3 can somehow, but that's clearly not the case here

Comment: Background images cannot stretch unless you use the `background-size` property. Firefox is probably the problematic one here.

Comment: What could be the ultimate solution then? So that it looks exactly as it looks now in Firefox?

Comment: @KPL: The easiest would be to just edit your image and make it 125px? Could we see some more code - it could be interfering with the current styles that you have.

Comment: @BoltClock , here you go - http://movie-buffs.info/

Comment: @KPL: It looks fine on Chrome 8 on Windows. Sounds like a Linux Chrome bug to me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So chrome was automatically taking up background-size from another css file.

When I put

> background-size: auto auto !important;

in `#header`,

the issue was gone.

Thanks everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

The shorthand you are using for background, is placing the color `#FFFFFF` in the last argument, it's supposed to be in the first.  Try getting rid of the shorthand, so your code will look like this:

```
 /* background: url(images/header-bg.png) top repeat-x #FFFFFF;    */
 background-image: url(images/header-bg.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-color: #fff;
 background-position: top;
```

Shorthand order:

```
background-color, background-image, background-repeat, background-attachment, background-position
```

Comment: Reasonable, although I can't see how this will cause weird stretching on a background...

Comment: @BoltClock, yes I think the problem is as you suggested, something else interfering.